# 仮想マシンに割り当てるメモリの値の常識

Tags: vmware

こんにちは。

仮想マシンに割り当てるメモリの値の常識についての質問です。

例えば物理マシンに128 GBのメモリを積んでいて
VMware ハイパーバイザをインストールしている際、
20 GB の仮想マシン x6
のように(16 GB, 32 GB のような) 2のn乗数値でないメモリの値を割り当てても問題ないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**物理**マシンでメモリを2のn乗で搭載することが多いのは、「デュアルチャネル」での動作を意識してのことでしょう(同容量・同規格のメモリを2枚組で構成することでデータ処理の高速化が見込める)。

**仮想**マシンの場合、割り当てできるのはあくまで「合計のメモリ容量」なので、デュアルチャネルはおそらく関係なく2のn乗に特別こだわる必要もないと思います。

Answer (score 2):

"OSから見える"物理メモリのサイズに2のべき乗であるべきという制限はありません。
なので、必要なだけメモリを割り当てればよいです。
たとえばご自分のPCに4x2 + 8Gのメモリを実装したりとかしませんか？＜これすごく効率悪いんですけど、予算の都合上、こうなっちゃったとか。。。
気になるのは、その状態で全部使いきったとしてホストOSで8Gって大丈夫ですか？って話と、今後仮想マシンを増設しようとしても、同時起動できない状態がうまれそうということぐらいですかね。オーバーコミットしてやり過ごすという手もなくはないでしょうが。。